# Add a button to an ag-grid column header

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a default ag-grid header, that is configured just like I need it. It is not movable, it is pinned and stuff like that. Now I have the challenge that seemed pretty simple but perhaps is the hardest thing to do using ag-grid - just spend the last two days on this...

I just want to add one little button that I can react on in my angular component.

I tried it with [Header Templates](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/): I can add a button here but I am not able to react on the click event.

Then I tried [Header Components](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/) but then, I have to take care of all the different features like sorting, filtering, menu, styling, ... Result: Suddenly, I can move the former pinned column around, it looks different than the other columns and and and. Just hell!

What is the easiest way to add a button to one column header but keep the styling and functionality just as it is?

**UPDATE**
After playing around with the ag-grid demo code from ag-grid, trying to use Header Components, I am back trying to use Header Templates. My current solution is to use the template to add my buttons and to wire up the events in code on the GridReady event. Something like:

```
<div class="ag-cell-label-container" role="presentation">
    <span ref="eMenu" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-cell-menu-button"></span>
    <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation">
        <div>
            <span id="ID1"><i class="someclass1"></i></span>
            <span id="ID2"><i class="someclass2"></i></span>
        </div>

        <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-order"></span>
        <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon"></span>
        <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-descending-icon"></span>
        <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-none-icon"></span>
        <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" role="columnheader"></span>
        <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-filter-icon"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then to wire up the events:

```
const elm1: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('ID1') as HTMLElement;
Observable.fromEvent(elm1, 'click').takeWhile(() => this._isAlive).subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Logic
});
```

Seems to work but I definitely hope that there is a more professional way to do it...

Comment: Share the code what you had tried so far.

Comment: @SunilSingh It is not so easy to share the code as I am trying around here a lot. But basically for the Header Components, I am using the demo code from ag-grid as a basis, the same is true for the Header Templates. I posted my current code/ solution in the update above.

Comment: Header template is useful only if you want to customize the presentation of your header. If you want the header to have a button and respond to click then custom header component must be used

Comment: In my opinion ag-grid solved this in a much too complex way. I really don't want to use a custom header for this simple scenario as this requires to mimic the default behavior and design - with all the related problems in doing something like that. My approach mentioned above is a little bit ugly but still less ugly the using a custom header component. But this is only my personal opinion although I do hope that ag-grid will provide a better solution in the future.

Comment: can you post a fiddle or plunker with what youve done?

Comment: Don't know if I will find time to do so. The most important bits of my solution are posted in my question above. But if you have a specific question I will try to answer it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In React agGrid I did what you need. Hope it helps.
I did it with custom header example in agGrid 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#example-header-component

In Column defs, as an example I added expandAll property

```
[{
    headerName: "Group",
    field: "group",
    expandAll: true
}]
```

in CustomHeader.js

```
let expand = null;
if (this.props.api.getColumnDef(this.props.column.colId).expandAll) {
    let text = this.state.expanded ? 'Collapse' : 'Expand';
    xpand = <span onClick={this.onExpandRequested.bind(this)}>{text}</span>
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>{expand}{headerTitle}{sort}</React.Fragment>
);

onExpandRequested (isExpanded) {

    if (this.state.expanded) {

        this.props.api.collapseAll();
    } else {

        this.props.api.expandAll();
    }
    this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old post, but it doesn't seem to have an elegant answer yet.  The op came close, but it only works for a single id and doesn't play nice with sorting the header.  My solution is as follows:

Update the template with a custom clickable element:

```
...
<div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation">
    <a href onclick="agHandleClick(event)" ref="eCustomButton" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-cell-custom-button"></a>
    <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" role="columnheader"></span>
...
</div>
```

In onGridReady, add the "agHandleClick" function to windows:

```
let _window: Window = window;
_window['agHandleClick'] = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // Logic
    console.log('header click', event);
};
```

Comment: This will not work at well configured production servers as they prevent inline constructs like <a href onclick="agHandleClick(event)"...